# Firebase background push notification Most of times are not received. Why?

Tags: ios, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

We are developing a chat system for iOS, and we are using Firebase to deliver notification to devices.
We will use `content-available` notification that will pass new messages data to the client. Then, client will save it and use this data to generate local notifications.
The example of notification payload we pass from our backend to FCM is:

```
       { 
     "data": { 
       "body": "{\"conversation_type\":\"single\",\"conversation_title\":\"mail@example.com\",\"truncated\":false,\"type\":\"new_message\",\"message\":{\"date\":1576508405933,\"conversation_id\":\"02c4d68c-bbdc-42f8-8be8-84ba383406b7/2
dcaec12-b979-4599-88f1-97cf8b9602d2\",\"from\":\"02c4d68c-bbdc-42f8-8be8-84ba383406b7\",\"id\":\"d72b9879-c832-46a8-a98d-75fd6a43198e\",\"text\":\"TEXT \",\"type\":\"text\"}}"                                                            
     }, 
     "android": { 
       "priority": "high" 
     }, 
     "apns": { 
       "headers": { 
         "apns-push-type": "background", 
         "apns-priority": "5" 
       }, 
       "payload": { 
         "aps": { 
           "content-available": 1 
         } 
       } 
     }, 
     "token": "device_token" 
   }
```

We don't understand which is the behaviour that this payload is having, but it works 30 times in a row and then doesn't work anymore for hours or days. Sometimes doesn't work without a single success case.
What is going wrong?

Comment: For chat functionality, why not use the more-common alert notification that will display an alert when the app is closed or in the background and call a method when the app is in the foreground? Why use a lower-priority background push type?

Comment: @bsod because common notifications doesn't trigger application to save messages on local database, so at startup application must authenticate itself and request new messages, taking some seconds to update the messages. Why whatsapp and telegram can update on background?

Comment: I would not make a remote notification responsible for writing to a database. When userA sends a message to userB, userA should write to the database and send a remote message to userB. If that message never arrives, for whatever reason (because it does happen), who cares? The message has been written to the database. If userB has the app closed, there is no work to be done; when they open the app, it will open to fresh data. If userB has the open, the UI updates in realtime anyway.